# Nvidia Graphics Driver for system with Dual GPU, GTX670MX and Intel Onchip Graphics Installation for Linux Mint (aka: Hybrid Graphics)

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card

I appear to have broken my system by following various instructions on the web on what graphics driver I should or should not be installing on my system. I recently installed (or thought I had installed) a newer version of my graphics driver - but now I cannot get steam to run. In addition I cannot run `glxspheres`.

The instructions I followed are [here](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=154932).

I notice that problems started after Step 7. After rebooting, my screen resolution is 1080p (not as it should be according to the instructions).

**I am unable to stop `mdm` after this step! Every time I try to stop the desktop manger, my system hangs.**

In addition, if I log in then I get an error message about the display configuration being unable to be set. Then the screen auto-adjusts to the 1080p (again).

**I do not think this information is useful, and I do not know if I installing the Nvidia driver is the correct thing to do.** I don't know if my system is broken because of a driver conflict, or because the Nvidia installation did not succeed. According to this question, *installing Nvidia graphics drivers from Nvidia for Linux is a bad idea* but the post does not explain why. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/is-a-nvidia-geforce-with-optimus-technology-supported-by-ubuntu).

**Also note that most of this information is massively out of date, so it probably isn't particularly helpful of me to provide links to questions from more than a year ago.**

Last time I did this was some years ago, and I used to have to run programs which required the Nvidia GTX graphics hardware rather than the Intel onchip graphics hardware using `optirun` or `primusrun`. I don't know what the difference is between them or whether I even require these anymore? (Have graphics drivers been updated to switch between the two automatically yet?)

I am on Linux Mint 17. Really I would like to start all over again with Mint 17.2, fresh install, but unfortunately I can't do that as I have some work to complete on the laptop I am using before I can risk running a fresh install.

I would like to know:

- How to wipe my system of all previously installed Nvidia graphics drivers. Both those acquired with `apt-get`, and automatic driver manager software, *and* those installed from a `.run` file downloaded directly from Nvidia.
- What graphics driver I should install for my hardware. (I know I have a GTX670MX, but there are different versions - perhaps the latest version number is the best option?)
- Where and how to get this driver (web download from nvidia / `apt-get` etc).
- How to install the driver.
- How to check it is working.
- How to install `optirun` and `primusrun` if I still need these?

I tried to remove the graphics driver by running the command `nvidia-uninstall` - it seems to have worked? But I might have just broken my system even more.

*Possible Answer*

I seem to have fixed the problem by following these instructions.

https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/5/828939163894026239/#c558746995129177020

> 1: Purging and autoremove
>   sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* nvidia* sudo apt-get autoremove
>
> 2: installation of bumblebee sudo apt-get install bumblebee primus
>   primus-libs-ia32:i386 linux-headers-generic
>
> 3: RESTART SYSTEM
>
> 4: installation of nvidia driver sudo apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia
>   nvidia-331
>
> 5: RESTART SYSTEM
>
> 6: start Steam optirun --bridge primus steam

I have not added this as an answer as I am unsure of how or why this solves the problem, or if the problem really is "fixed".

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: My vote was issue because you reference some instructions  you followed without telling us what they were.

Comment: @Ramhound May I please have an upvote now?

Comment: The instructions very specifically indicated that if you have a dGPU from either AMD or Nvidia and an iGPU from Intel the instructions shouldn't have been used.  What specific version of the Nvidia driver did you install?

Comment: Additionally the link you provided says very specifically the reason you cannot use the generic Nvidia drivers, if your laptop implements a Optimus, that is because and I quote "hat the discrete Nvidia card is wired into the integrated Intel GPU and that it's not connected to a monitor at all." which basically means you need both drivers installed for your display to function correctly.   So does your card implement a hat the discrete Nvidia card is wired into the integrated Intel GPU an Optimus design?

Comment: @Ramhound Which instructions are you referring to here? I provided 2? I tried to install NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-355.11

Comment: @Ramhound I have no idea in regards to your second comment - I don't fully understand what you are asking or how to check to give you an answer

Comment: The instructions in the first link.  You need to solve your inability to stop mdm, and that problem, is sort of separate from your other questions.  As for how to uninstall the drivers, after you stop mdm, you simply run `sudo sh N-355.11.run --uninstall` or whatever the .run file is named.

Comment: @Ramhound I was able to stop `mdm` before I attempted the installation instructions I provided a link to. (First link) If you haven't already, please re-read the question as I explain what went wrong.

Comment: I read your question in the following context, you followed the instructions, and you currently are unable to stop `mdm` because of a permission problem related to your configuration.  If you cannot stop `mdm` you cannot revert the changes you have made. The instructions provided by `roblm` on the second of the page is what you should have followed.  Alternatively on the first page, just follow, the 4-step instructions on page 1